# What is the sum of the range of 2 numbers?

Tags: java, loops, sum, int

I want to sum the range of values between two numbers. I prompt the user for the 2 numbers, and if the first number is greater then I want to swap it with the second number before I loop. How can I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, count = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter two limits: ");
        n1 = kb.nextInt();
        n2 = kb.nextInt();

        while ( n1 <= n2 ) {
            count = count + n2;
            n2--;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum from "+ n1 +" to "+ n2 +" is : " + count);
    }
}
```

and the output I want tells me (if I type 6 and 10)

```
the sum from 6 to 10 is 40
```

but my program output is

```
the sum from 6 to 5 is 40
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry that my mistake , but i mean if the user input the bigger first the program should swap the numbers to be the first number are lower

Comment: `n2--` is decrementing your input value

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use `Math.max(int, int)` and `Math.min(int, int)` (and an `IntStream`, assuming you're using Java 8+). Like,

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter two limits: ");
int n1 = kb.nextInt();
int n2 = kb.nextInt();
int start = Math.min(n1, n2), stop = Math.max(n1, n2);
System.out.println("The sum from " + n1 + " to " + n2 + " is : "
        + IntStream.rangeClosed(start, stop).sum());
```

If you can't use `Math` for some reason, or a very convenient little trick, you could do some *math* of your own; like

```
int start = n1;
if (n2 < n1) {
    start = n2;
}
int stop = n2 + n1 - start;
```

**or**

```
int start = (n1 < n2) ? n1 : n2, stop = n2 + n1 - start;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int n1;
int n2;
int count = 0;

System.out.print("Enter two limits: ");
n1 = in.nextInt();
n2 = in.nextInt();
if (n1 > n2) {
    n1 += n2;
    n2 = n1 - n2;
    n1 -= n2;
}
int current = n1;
while (current <= n2) {
    count += current;
    current++;
}
System.out.println("The sum from " + n1 + " to " + n2 + " is : " + count);
```